# GCP Autoscaling based on memory (stackdriver)

Tags: google-compute-engine, google, autoscaling, google-stackdriver

I want to configure autoscaling based on memory using stackdriver metrics.
I've installed stackdriver agent on VM and when I'm trying to configure Instance groups and I choose stackdriver metrics. I've got information `This feature is not available for this project.`

Could help me?

Answer (score 1):

This error appears to suggest that you’re using the Stackdriver Basic Tier which allows ‘Logging agent only’ as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing), section ‘Stackdriver account service tiers’.

I presume you would need the Premium Tier:

```
Basic Tier: Stackdriver VM agents Logging agent only        

Premium Tier: Logging agent and Monitoring agent
```

The Basic Tier is free. It provides basic features, a moderate allotment of logs, and access to built-in metrics. If you try using metrics other than the built-in ones, you may get this error.

As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/) the Monitoring agent's metrics are only available with the Stackdriver Premium service tier.